# I can't change row's background color in table

Tags: html, css, frontend

I can't change rows' `background-color`; I'd like to have one row red.

Here is my code:

```css
table.cennik-table {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #555555;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table.cennik-table th {
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #888888;
}

table.cennik-table td {
  padding: 0.7rem;
}

table.cennik-table tr.rowB {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="cennik-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Ilość wejść</th>
      <th>Zajęcia grupowe</th>
      <th>Treningi personalne</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rowB">
      <td>1x tydzień</td>
      <td>20zł</td>
      <td rowspan="4">50zł</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rowA">
      <td>2x tydzień</td>
      <td>60zł</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rowB">
      <td>3x tydzień</td>
      <td>110zł</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="rowA">
      <td>OPEN</td>
      <td>160zł</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner so I could have made some simple mistakes.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, could you please fix your message?

Comment: It appears to be working (two rows are red). What problem are you having?